# Spring WS client access to HTTP response

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, spring-ws

How can I get access to the MessageContext/HTTP Response in the client using Spring WS as a client, when the SOAP message response generates an exception?

Answer (score 0):

By using the `TransportContext`. See here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/common.html#transport-context

Comment: Poutsam, I tried that, but after calling webserviceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(), the exception is thrown.  In the block where I catch the exception, TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext() returns null.

Comment: Yes, the holder will only contain the context when the connection is still open. So you'll have to put the code in a `WebServiceMessageCallback` or `WebServiceMessageExtractor` and use one of the `WebServiceTemplate` variants that take that as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the result in the WebServiceMessageExtractor available outside of the callback?  I get an error that I can't refer to non-final variable.  message.getPayloadResult() will read the full HTTP payload and i just need to call it once?